# Spring security after login response 302 and shows ROLE_ANONYMOUS Access Denied

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt

html:

```
<form th:action="@{/com/login}" method="post">
            <label for="username">User account:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>

            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>

                <label for="remember_me">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="remember_me"> Remember me
                </label>
            <a href="#">Forget password?</a>

            <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>
```

Security configure :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigure {

    private final RSAKeyProperties keys;

    public SecurityConfigure(RSAKeyProperties keys) {
        this.keys = keys;
    }
    
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(UserDetailsService detailsService) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoProvider.setUserDetailsService(detailsService);
        daoProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return new ProviderManager(daoProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        
        http.csrf(csrf -> 
        csrf.disable())
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
            auth.requestMatchers("/auth/**", "/com/**").permitAll();
            auth.requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
            auth.requestMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER");
            auth.requestMatchers("/authenticated/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER");
            auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
        });
        
        http.formLogin(form -> {
            form.loginPage("/com/loginHome");
            form.loginProcessingUrl("/com/login");
            form.defaultSuccessUrl("/authenticated/home");
            form.successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler);
        });
        

        http.sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        http.oauth2ResourceServer(
                oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter())));
        
        return http.build();
    }
    

    private Consumer<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.Builder> authorizationRequestCustomizer() {
        return customizer -> customizer
                    .additionalParameters(params -> params.put("prompt", "consent"));
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(keys.getPublicKey()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(keys.getPublicKey()).privateKey(keys.getPrivateKey()).build();
        JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");

        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);

        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }
    

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return web -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/css/*.css", "/image/get/*", "/image/get/carousel/*",
                "/images/*", "/images/logo/*", "/js/*.js");
    }

}
```

controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/com")
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class CommonController {
    
    private SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository =  new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();
    
    private final SecurityContextHolderStrategy securityContextHolderStrategy = SecurityContextHolder.getContextHolderStrategy();
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;
    
    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String home() {
        return "main/index2";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/loginHome")
    public String loginPage() {
        return "main/loginPage";
    }
        

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(@RequestParam Map<String, String> loginInfo, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model m) {
        LoginResponseDTO loginUser = null;
        try {
            if(!MapUtils.isEmpty(loginInfo)) {
                loginUser = authenticationService.loginUser(loginInfo.get("username"), loginInfo.get("password"));
            } else {
                m.addAttribute("error", "Invalid username or password");
                 return "main/loginPage";
            }
            if(loginUser.getUser() != null) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(
                        loginInfo.get("username"), loginInfo.get("password"));
                Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
                SecurityContext context = securityContextHolderStrategy.createEmptyContext();
                context.setAuthentication(authentication);
                securityContextHolderStrategy.setContext(context);
                securityContextRepository.saveContext(context, request, response);
                return "redirect:/authenticated/home";
            } else {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user not found");
            }
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException e) {
          m.addAttribute("error", "Invalid username or password");
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          m.addAttribute("error", "Something went wrong. Please try again later.");
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
        return "main/loginPage";
    }

    
}
```

Issue 1 :
When declare `form.loginProcessingUrl("/com/login");` that `/com/login` not event executed.

Issue 2:
When `form.loginProcessingUrl("/com/login");` not been declared. The `/com/login` will execute but will response 302. As following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLQ5w.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeZHg.png)

And the console shows :

```
2024-02-28T08:26:45.099+08:00[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m25656[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8080-exec-10][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.s.r.w.a.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Did not process request since did not find bearer token
[2m2024-02-28T08:26:45.099+08:00[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m25656[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8080-exec-10][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (9/14)
[2m2024-02-28T08:26:45.099+08:00[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m25656[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8080-exec-10][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (10/14)
[2m2024-02-28T08:26:45.099+08:00[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m25656[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8080-exec-10][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (11/14)
[2m2024-02-28T08:26:45.099+08:00[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m25656[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8080-exec-10][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking SessionManagementFilter (12/14)
[2m2024-02-28T08:26:45.099+08:00[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m25656[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8080-exec-10][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
[2m2024-02-28T08:26:45.099+08:00[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m25656[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8080-exec-10][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=600F3CB34A220619D8A4042AB3AA44F3], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
[2m2024-02-28T08:26:45.099+08:00[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m25656[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8080-exec-10][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (13/14)
[2m2024-02-28T08:26:45.099+08:00[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m25656[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8080-exec-10][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking AuthorizationFilter (14/14)
[2m2024-02-28T08:26:45.099+08:00[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m25656[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8080-exec-10][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@34c2aac6]
[2m2024-02-28T08:26:45.099+08:00[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m25656[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8080-exec-10][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@34c2aac6] using AuthorityAuthorizationManager[authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER]]
[2m2024-02-28T08:26:45.099+08:00[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m25656[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8080-exec-10][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=600F3CB34A220619D8A4042AB3AA44F3], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:128) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:225) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) ~[na:na]
```

I've tried a lot of ways, but none seem to work. At this point, I believe there's an issue with the authorization process. It seems like the subsequent pages(/authenticated/**) requiring a bearer token aren't receiving it properly. I attempted to follow the recommendations on the official website by manually setting up authentication, but the problem persists.

I hope someone can assist me in resolving this issue. Thank you.

I was trying to set authentication in login method but it seems the authentication information not propagate.